# How do I deploy the package.json version id to AppEngine flexible environment --version argument?

Tags: google-app-engine, npm, package.json

AppEngine Flexible Environment deploys using `gcloud app deploy` are generally slow because AppEngine has to spin up the container environment before deploying the code and switching traffic to it.

A common method to speed up the deployment is to specify the version, that way AppEngine deploys new code to the same container environment. Such as:

`gcloud app deploy --version=12345`

In a node environment, I would like to use the package.json version in my deploy scripts, for example:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.3.4",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy":"gcloud app deploy --version=$npm_package_version"        
  }
```

NPM takes the values in the config and adds it to environment variables prefixed with $npm_package_ out of the box so that's fine.

However, AppEngine does not accept `.` in their version names.

So I am looking for a good way to transform $npm_package_version into an AppEngine-approved version number before being able to pass it into `gcloud` on the `<scripts>` node.

Comment: A still good question. I'm also looking for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a simple solution that works for me.

Below my troncated `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "GAE_VERSION=$(echo ${npm_package_version} | sed 's/\\./-/g') && gcloud app deploy --version $GAE_VERSION"
  },
  "dependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

This is - in fact - pretty simple.

1. get `npm_package_version` and change with `sed` `.` by `-` (GAE is ok with hyphen)
2. Assign the result to a variable (here : `GAE_VERSION`)
3. Use `gcloud` command to deploy using `GAE_VERSION` variable.

Comment: Ah good call, it isn't the solution I ended up using (I just wrote a bash script and call that from scripts instead) but it answers the question as asked.