# How to use the result of an NPM script in another NPM script?

Tags: bash, variables, npm, package.json

It might be simple. But I can't get it work.

Let's consider the simple (and troncated) `package.json` below.

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "TEST": "1-0-0",
  "scripts": {
    "TEST_IN_SCRIPTS": " echo ${npm_package_version} | sed 's/\\./-/g' ",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy --version ${npm_package_scripts_TEST_IN_SCRIPTS}"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to `deploy` an app with `--version` equals `version` (aka `1.0.0`).
However, Google App Engine does not allow `.` (dot).

The idea is then to deploy a `1-0-0` (instead of `1.0.0`) which is allowed by GAE.

`TEST_IN_SCRIPTS` works and returns `1-0-0`
However, when I pass `${npm_package_scripts_TEST_IN_SCRIPTS}` to `deploy` script, it fails because it returns the string `${npm_package_scripts_TEST_IN_SCRIPTS}` instead of its result `(1-0-0)`.

Any clue to make it works?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a simple solution that works for me. 
Thanks @Juan, you show me the road!

Below my troncated package.json

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "GAE_VERSION=$(echo ${npm_package_version} | sed 's/\\./-/g') && gcloud app deploy --version $GAE_VERSION"
  },
  "dependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

This is - in fact - pretty simple.

1. get `npm_package_version` and change with `sed` `.` by `-` (GAE is ok with hyphen)
2. Assign the result to a variable (here : `GAE_VERSION`)
3. Use `gcloud` command to deploy using `GAE_VERSION` variable.

An [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065007/how-do-i-deploy-the-package-json-version-id-to-appengine-flexible-environment/50689057#50689057) where I post this very same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output of the `TEST_IN_SCRIPTS`:

`"deploy": "npm run TEST_IN_SCRIPTS | xargs gcloud app deploy --version",`

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work: `--version` needs an argument ... `--version/-v: expected one argument`. Both scripts run, but no version number is "attached" to `--version`...

Comment: I updated it. I put it backwards. My bad. First the TEST IN SCRIPTS must run and then pass the output to the gcloud command. Plz try again.

Comment: Same thing.. :-( . I need to pass to `gcloud` something "complete", like `gcloud app deploy --version 1-0-0`...

Comment: @nerotulip I updated it by adding xargs so the output of your TEST_IN_SCRIPTS is parsed as an arg on version. Please try again 

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.